# 'C:\OpenCV-3.3.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world330d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

What should I do when I get this message?

> (Win32): Loaded 'C:\OpenCV-3.3.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world330d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Not only in this file, but I get it in the others as well.

OpenCV v3.3, Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: This is not a question.  Ask something that actually means something, no one knows what should you do because we don't know what you want to do.   I'm guess what you really want is `How can I generate a PDB File to Debug DLL`

Comment: ***What should i do when i get this message ?*** Probably ignore it. Although it depends on if you think you need to debug the implementation of opencv yourself. Sometimes it is helpful if you are passing a wrong argument to a function to see how that function responds to your bad data. In either case this does not stop your application from running if that is your problem.

Comment: ***im new at programming.*** Then definitely ignore this warning. This is for more advanced programmers.

Answer (score 0):

PDB is for debugging with DLL library. Thinks are little bit complicated but one think you can ignore this.. The PDB is created when you are compile C/C++ program with /ZI or /Zi settings. It could happened when you compile wrong opencv program with wrong settings. I think also that version opencv 3.3.0 have not build for VC141 visual studio 2017, and your library are just VC140. But not sure about this.

Comment: so opencv 3.3.0 doesn't fully support for vc141 ? ok, thanks. I will check it

Comment: You can build opencv yourself using the source code and CMake to generate a Visual Studio 2017 project. With that said this probably is not for your level being a person new at programming. Just ignore the warning.

Comment: I build by my self.. Maybe 3.3.0 already have it. Last time i build 3.2
https://funvision.blogspot.cz/2017/04/opencv-build-and-install-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, now there is a smarter solution with opencv and with most of the c++ packages out there there is a package manager called vcpkg.
vcpkg compiles the library from source. Therefore you don't need to worry about compiler compatability. So, installing opencv with vcpkg is as simple as
vcpkg install opencv ( this install 32 bit version)
For 64 bit version, it is as simple as
vcpkg install opencv:x64-windows
and with visual studio adding a library is something as simple as typing
vcpkg intgrate install
Consider using vcpkg for this
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg

Comment: You may first mention the cause of the problem the OP had, and how to resolve, or avoid it by using the latest feature as of today - this way your answer would be more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Well, this looks like a problem with the installation of opencv, or not referrencing it well. This can't be easily solved without access to the actual circumstances of the build and code. Therefore, I thought offering a solution that is both practical and easy to implement might be worth while.